# Can Someone tell me the reason of the segmentation fault - (core dumped) error in this program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Can someone help me with the `segmentation fault` error in the program.
I recently started working with linked list and I don't know if I used the `struct node` properly. If the use is wrong, can someone correct me. Thank You!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node
{
        int data;
        struct node* link;
};
struct node* root = NULL;
void append()
{
        struct node* temp;
        temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("Enter The Node Value: ");
        scanf("%d",&temp->data);
        temp->link=NULL;
        if(root = NULL)
        {
                root = temp;
        }
        else
        {
                struct node* p;
                p = root;
                while(p->link != NULL)
                {
                        p=p->link;
                }
                p = temp;
        }
}
int main()
{
        printf("Add A Node To The Structure:-\n");
        while(1)
        {
                int ch;
                printf("Enter 2 To Exit\n");
                printf("Enter Your Choice:");
                scanf("%d",&ch);
                switch(ch)
                {
                        case 2: exit(0);
                        default:append();
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if root = NULL`? Are you sure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if(root = NULL)` assigns null to root instead of checking.
Null is cast to boolean false, so the else block is executed.
Using `root` attributes assuming it's non null leads to segfault.
Write `if(root == NULL)` instead.